# iOS Safari: 'click' event not triggerd when there is an event-listener on 'mousemove'

Tags: javascript, safari, mouseevent

on safari in iOS when an element or an ancestor of it has an event listener on `mousemove` then the `click` event listener on it is ignored.

```
<div id="el"></div>

document.getElementById("el").addEventListener("mousemove", _e => console.log("mousemove"));
document.getElementById("el").addEventListener("click",     _e => console.log("click"));
```

on ios the click is never logged, on android (chrome) or desktop browsers, both are.

there are dozens stackoverflow questions regarding ios click bugs, but i couldn't find any about this combination.

Comment: Is this code the actual code you're having this issue with? I tried it and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Mikael Lennholm , yes pretty much. (except that i change a text instead of using console log) i am using ios version 9.3.1

Comment: @Mikael, i put a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ld2ah10/1/ , if i open the jsfiddle it works also for me (click and mousemove)! i copied the markup+js+css to my project i have literally exact the same code as in the fiddle but when i open from my local node server i see only the mousemove being logged.

Comment: "...except that i change a text instead of using console log". That's a pretty important difference. Here's an excerpt from Apple's document describing how Safari uses touch input to emulate mouse events: *if the contents of the page changes on the mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent* (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Comment: I don't understand why it works in the fiddle though, maybe Apple's algorithm for determining if a change is relevant or not has become more clever and takes contextual information into account.

Comment: @Mikael, i think you are absolutely right with the 'page changes on the mousemove' from apple document. Would you like to post that as the answer or should i?

Comment: I'd be happy to make an answer out of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an excerpt from Apple's own document describing how Safari on iOS uses touch inputs to emulate mouse events:

> ...events arrive in this order: `mouseover`, `mousemove`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `click`. [...] if the contents of the page changes on the `mousemove` event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

In other words, if you do some alteration to the DOM in your `mousemove` event handler (and not just a simple `console.log()`), the `click` event will be deferred, according to Apple's spec.
Back when the iPhone was introduced, this was Apple's way of dealing with the fact that an actual mouse pointer can be used for hover effects while a touch can not.

Though, I'm not sure why the click event isn't deferred in the simple fiddle. It could be that the algorithm used is more "clever" these days and determines if a DOM alteration is relevant by assessing what changed and factoring in contextual information.